# Pull images from multiple sheets in Google Sheets - without Query! (because it does not recognize images in cells)

Tags: image, google-sheets, tabs

I am making a photo directory.

EDIT: Here is the example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qo2ku9JuuNsX_v-D47nS8DLxvdqvpoNhRbZat2970Kw/edit?usp=sharing

I have one sheet with STAFF information that includes images in Column C. I have a second sheet with MEMBER information that also includes images in Column C. I want a third sheet to autofill first from STAFF and then from MEMBERS.

Query works great for all the data except the images. It appears not to recognize images in the cells as data. Even when I Query Column C alone it says there is no data.

Beyond query, most other formulas recognize photos in sheets and reproduce them in other sheets, including INDEX MATCH, FILTER, and a simple ARRAYFORMULA that pulls from a sheet with photos.

TO keep my third sheet flexible, so that it pulls all rows from STAFF and then all rows from MEMBERS, however long they may be, I'm looking for a single formula that could accomplish this.

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can further help you.

Comment: Nope, I did not downvote your post, here's the proof: https://snipboard.io/2dGBXc.jpg  It would be really helpful if you can provide a dummy sheet.

Comment: Okay thanks, been working for hours and can't find a solution, sorry I'm a little jumpy. Here's the Example Page: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qo2ku9JuuNsX_v-D47nS8DLxvdqvpoNhRbZat2970Kw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,vstack(STAFF!A2:D,MEMBERS!A2:D),
     filter(Σ,choosecols(Σ,1)<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: THAT WORKED! At the same time I came up with the following which also works: `={FILTER(STAFF!A3:AN,STAFF!A3:A<>"");FILTER(MEMBERS!A2:AN,MEMBERS!A2:A<>"")}` To anyone paying attention, the number of columns must be the same in both expressions in both answers. My Staff page had fewer columns, but to get all the columns from Members I had to add blank columns to Staff. Thanks again!

Comment: **1.** `vstack` variant can withstand different amount of columns. You can use it as such `ifna(vstack(STAFF!A2:C,MEMBERS!A2:D))` *STAFF* with 3 columns and *MEMBERS* with 4  for example **2.** `vstack` variant will also work in an odd scenario when one of the tabs has no data et all but the `{}` style will throw an error